# How to get current date and time of user laptop not server in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have deployed the angular app on the server, but I want to get my system (laptop) date and time in the application.

Suppose the server has the date and time of timeZoneA while my laptop has date and time of TimeZoneB, so basically, I want that timeZoneB should be shown in the application opened in the browser of my laptop.

```
this.currentDateTime = new Date();
```

I can get date and time of any specific zone. but it's not requirement.

```
formatDate(new Date(),'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a','en-US','+0500');
```

Comment: `but I am not getting my system date and time.` What does this mean- Server or desktop/laptop/mobile device?

Comment: I updated the question. @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: What are you getting can you add the code where are you including this piece of code?

Comment: I updated the question. basically, the server is in CountryA where angular app is deployed while I am in CountryB using my laptop, so I want to get CountryB time, not CountryA time.

Comment: Call `new Date()` in fronted and you should get the laptop date.

Comment: It doesn't matter where your app is deployed if it is a frontend code, it should give the time of the current device it's executed on. It seems you are not providing the correct details.

Comment: @RickyMo angular app is deployed on the server, and new Date() is written there.
while I have opened that application in the browser of my laptop.

Comment: yes, I was also expecting so that I should get date and time of my laptop not the server but unfortunately it's not working so. I am getting the server date and time.

Answer (score 1):

In the question you are passing the timezone in formatDate so that is why you are getting the specific timezone date.

Remove the timezone from formatDate to the local date and time.

change :

```
formatDate(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a','en-US','+0500');
```

to :

```
date = formatDate(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US');
```

If you want to get the time of specific time zone :

```
function getTime(){
    //timeZone can be  "CST","GMT" ,"Asia/Jerusalem" , etc
    var d = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "CST"}));
    var n = d.toLocaleString(); // just to get date & time
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that for a specific time zone it can be done.

Comment: @NaveedUllah updated my answer

Comment: I am not using formatDate in the application and neither I am passing time zone to Date object.  I am using only this to get current date and time . this.currentDateTime = new Date();

Comment: Can you please check the your local time here https://time.is/  just to be sure your local time is correct.

Comment: My laptop time is correct. and confirmed in time.is too.

Comment: can you share the server link ?